# Ksh arithmetic anomaly

Tags: shell, ksh

I have the following lines in a script:

```
NR_OF_REQUESTS_IN_PROGRESS=$(db2 -x "select count(*) from my_table where date='$MY_DATE' and status = 'EXPECTED_STATUS' and id in ($CURRENT_ID, $OTHER_ID)" | awk '{print $1}')
while [[ $NR_OF_REQUESTS_IN_PROGRESS -gt 0 ]]; do
  [...]
done
```

Now this works perfectly in my env, yet when a colleague of mine tests it, he gets an *arithmetic syntax error* for that line. How come?

Comment: and what does your colleague's screen show if you add `set -vx` before the assignment to `NR_OF_REQ..`s. ? This almost certainly that the call to `db2` is not returning a numeric value. Good luck.

Comment: Please make it an answer so I can accept that. His db2 instance returned with an error message.

Comment: If you write an appropriate `select` statement to produce only one column, you won't need to use `awk` to output just the first column.

Comment: @chepner the select produces only one column that is padded. awk just removes the padding so -gt 0 will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your colleague's screen show if you add `set -vx` before the assignment to `NR_OF_REQ..`s. ?

The problem is almost certainly  that the call to db2 is not returning a numeric value.

Just remember, `set -vx` is your friend (even if it is rather unwieldy when dealing with large and/or nested while/for/if-then-else-fi blocks of code :-) )

IHTH